# Confusing tag excerpt edit rejections

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, rejection-reasons

I've been filling some new tags excerpts and I am confused about getting rejected a few times. There's one guy who's particularly... keen on rejecting. I've been wondering if someone could tell me what are his reasons, and perhaps give me some hints on what an excerpt should contain if my excerpts are invalid.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2493957
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2493951
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2493923

Comment: Just because a user has cast rejection votes on a few of your suggestions doesn't mean he's "keen" on rejecting (with an ellipsis or without). And he does give his reason right there (that the edit is too minor: and to be fair, some of the additions are pretty short). If others don't vote that the edit is too minor it doesn't matter, and if others do than maybe there's something to it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I took a look at his stats, he has over 66% rejection rate, he is definitely "keen". But most importantly, I would like to know his resoning to make the edits better.

Comment: Just reading them, they seem a bit...short.  I realize tag wiki excerpts aren't supposed to be epics, but a bit cleaner grammar and slightly more clarity into what it's supposed to be wouldn't *hurt*.  Then again, I've mostly shied away from tag edits, since I'm not entirely comfortable with the standards for it yet...

Comment: @Makoto before starting editing tag information I looked at the most popular tags and read their descriptions. I try to use simiar style and try to be objective: no opinions, just facts, and only the most important (other info would go into the description).

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the person you're targeting, but I'll give you my feedback on your three suggestions.

#### [openrpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2493957)

> a standalone report generator application which uses SQL to get data from various databases

Passable. I'd like to know in what environment this application runs and what kind of reports it generates. Half the sentence is devoted to “which uses SQL to get data from various databases” which is redundantly repetitious in triplicate — each of “SQL”, “get data” and “databases” conveys fundamentally the same idea.

[I've reworded](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17608378/3) the part about databases to mention PostgreSQL as it seems to be the primary target. I've added “GUI-driven”, which seems important: when I read your excerpt, the first thing that came to mind was a program that you'd run on a server and that would use some predefined template. I left the OS support out because all major desktop OSes are supported so it isn't decisive information.

I also wrote a short tag wiki body. Even when you have nothing to add to the excerpt, it's a good idea to put substantially the same text in the body just to be able to link to the official website.

#### [lemoon](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2493951)

Ok. I can't think of information I'd like to add (but maybe someone who knows Lemoon would), except that ASP seems as important as .NET (and it's only three characters, so the cognitive cost of adding it is very low). However please pay special attention to grammar and spelling in excerpts as they are meant to be displayed in a lot of places. It's “.NET”, not “.net”.

Again I've added a one-sentence tag wiki body with a link to the website.

#### [???](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2493923)

> a release of the Eclipse programming IDE, published in 2013

I presume that the tag name was `eclipse-4.3`, given that one reviewer expressed a preference for the name [eclipse-kepler](/questions/tagged/eclipse-kepler). The excerpt should have mentioned both the codename and the version number, as Eclipse releases are known under both designations.

Tags including a version number tend to be heavily abused on questions that are not specific to that version of the application. There should be prominent guidance to use the tag only for questions that are really version-specific, and to use the generic tag (here [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)) if unsure.

The tag was removed, it would have been better to keep it and make it a synonym with the other way to designate the version.